# That's could be a meteorite, what would be a good procedure to be sure?

Tags: composite-materials

[[image]]

I found it in Sahara desert(Africa),
three years ago. I think, it could be a meteorite.

Comment: Rock ID questions were banned as off-topic in Earth Science SE. Meteorite ID questions are not off topic here, but this question is currently impossible to answer. There's no way to ID from a photo. **Answers are all going to be opinions** and there's no way to judge which answer is correct. I'm voting to close as off-topic as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: However you could ask something along the lines of "I found something that I suspect of being a meteorite, what would be a good procedure for finding out?" But I think that would get a better answer in Earth Science SE. But don't ask "Is this a meteorite" as those are explicitly off-topic now (i.e. "banned".)

Comment: Unrelated to space exploration IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

The chance you actually found a meteorite is really tiny. So small actually, that the obligatory [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com) reference is actually really accurate:

[image: xkcd: Meteorite identification]

*(obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1723/))*

Jokes aside though, the comic does reference an actual procedure you might follow:

[image: meteorite self-test]
*(from [self-test check-list](http://meteorites.wustl.edu/check-list.htm))*

The [website](http://meteorites.wustl.edu/what_to_do.htm) this checklist comes from provides a ton of information on what to do to verify that what you have is a meteorite and what you can do with it if it is indeed a meteorite. Also, [a list of helpful examples and clarifications](http://meteorites.wustl.edu/realities.htm).

Note: the professor behind that page is now retired.

Comment: Thanks you, I did all the test that exist.